# Doing a clean install of Lion on a system purchased with Snow Leopard results in iPhoto lost. How to recover?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, photos.app

I am not terribly dependent on iPhoto, but I'd prefer not to purchase it via the App Store, as I already owned the app in Snow Leopard.

However, now that I have done a clean install of OS X Lion (did a complete format and used recovery mode to install Lion), it is not there.

**How can I install iPhoto on my system without repurchasing it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt need to buy it as it is included as part of the iLife suite which comes with all Macs.

From: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2604

1. Insert the Applications installation disc and double-click the Install Bundled Software icon.
2. If your computer came with an iLife installation disc, or you purchased a newer version of iLife, insert that disc instead.
3. Follow the onscreen instructions. Then, in the Installation Type pane, click Customize.
4. Click the disclosure triangle next to Bundled Applications, select the checkbox next to the application you want to install, then click Install.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac should have come with recovery disks, one with applications and another with the OS. You should be able to use the applications disk to install iPhoto and anything else that shipped with your Mac.

I tested this myself when I did the same thing at Lion's launch.